# PHP Laravel RESTful api for android questions

Tags: php, android, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to `Laravel` and not quite sure how to move my PHP code to Laravel

currently, I have an android app that communicates with the server with android volley throught a url `www.example.com/test.php`

android volley sends out some `POST` parameters ( example: `userID`, `RestaurantId` etc ) to the `.php` file

In the file it creates the correct `.json` structure from table(s) using `PDO` with prepared statements to connect to the db

then it returned a `.json` with `json_encode()`

how do I move this code to laravel?

do I really need an authorization/login page for this?

Comment: the laravel is framework, so there is an different formate. so first of all you need to understand structure and syntax of laravel.

Comment: Laravel doesn't work like a "pile of files" PHP app. Everything goes through [the router layer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing) that directs things to [controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers) as is typical in most MVC-style frameworks. If you're building an API you may not need authorization via username/password, but you will need an API key if there's anything protected, which usually is created by signing up and generating a key.

Comment: You should have a look at basic examples on how to create an api with laravel, but simplified all you need to do is to define the routes in app/http/routes.php which shall be accessed and either provider a controller or a function directly. You will need to take care of web middleware since you probably don't want this for an api.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do a bunch of stuff to achieve this. You will probably not be able to transform your code since laravel will do all the database communication using eloquent. Routing is also a completely different concept than in plain php.

I still highly recommend using laravel since you will have less security issues.

Here's a list of topics and steps you will need to have  a look at to achieve what you described.

- Assuming you have a fresh laravel setup with the newest version you will have to look at the web middleware which you probably don't need for an api. It can be found in the RouteServiceProvider where it is defined to be used on every route in your routes.php file. If you have an older version of Laravel 5.2 it might be defined as group in the routes.php itself. Remove web middleware and maybe add api middleware if needed
- Create routes in your routes.php file to define which "url" are used to respond to requests
- Create controllers to handle those incoming requests. If you do not have a lot of code you can handle them directly in the routes.php as anonymous function
- Models are basically your Tables. You should define a model for each of your tables. A user model is already defined by default. Have a look in it's code. You will also define relations between models. This will make CURD operators on linked models very easy.
- Migrations are the definitions of your tables. It consists of "what should be done when the migration is run" (up function) and "what should be done in case of a rollback" (down function)
- If you return classes / arrays in laravel it will automatically be parsed to json

Looking at your example I'd assume you will have a user model and a restaurant model if you for example have a vote system where a user votes / rates a restaurant you would have a many to many relationship between user and a restaurant.

if a restaurant belongs to an user it would be oneToMany since a user can have multiple restaurants.

Defining relations looks like this ( User.php Model )

```
public function restaurants() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Restaurants');
}
```

The Restaurant.php would look like this

```
public function user() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

With this setup ensure your Restaurant table has a "user_id" foreign key field to the user table.

Querying all restaurants of a user will now look like this

```
return $user->restaurants;
```

But these are just some high level examples which should explain to you how laravel works and why you can benefit from it. It reduces your boilerplate code and provides you with a solid set of functions, helpers and concepts that will help you to easily enhance your application - once it was set up.

You can have a look into the docs for more details https://laravel.com/docs/5.2
And find awesome tutorials at http://laracasts.com

Comment: If I do have an admin backend that requires authentification, and also the requests from android that do not requires any authentification, how do I setup the middleware to support both?

Comment: most of the JSON data returned from server from android requests are not sensitive or critical information ( email/password ), do I need to add authentication for this?

Comment: There is an auth middleware. You can look up tutorials for "incremental APIs" using basic auth for example. 
You can define a group using this middleware in your routes.php then you simply put all routes into this group that shall be protected. All the other routes can be put outside of this group and are unprotected.
You could also create two different controllers to implement this.